# Global instance of class in php

Tags: php, class, smarty, new-operator, slim

This is probably basic stuff, but I´m no trained developer so bear with me.

My question is: How can I get a class in php "global" so I can initialize it outside a function call, but still use it inside?

This example shows what I want to achieve, but does apparently not work:

```
$view = new Smarty();

$view->debugging = false;
$view->caching = false;
$view->cache_lifetime = 1;
$view->setTemplateDir('../views/');

$app->get('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) {    
    $param = $request->getParams();

    $view->assign('name', $param["name"]);
    $response = $view->display('index.html');

    return $response;
});
```

To get it to work I have to define it within the $app->get call. Then of course the $view->debugging etc also have to be set inside the $app->get call.

The purpose of this is to avoid having to initialize a new instance of $view for every call and get the default settings to be global.

Edit:
Maybe I was to quick asking the question here. After a google search I think I may found the solution. But using "global $view" inside the function I get access to the instance of the class. This is different from other languages where you set "public $variable = new class.function()" but there is probably a reason for it being so, and I can definitely see how this can be a advantage for security/performance etc. Is there any alternative way? What is the pro/cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global variables is not considered good practice; it makes for code that is very difficult to test. See [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/106252) You usually want to do dependency injection:

```
function doSomething($obj)
{
    // code here
}

$foo = new MyClass();
doSomething($foo);
```

Of course, that can be tricky when you're working with a potentially opinionated framework.

A better solution in your case is to use [the `use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to inherit the variable from the local scope instead of the global scope, as in:

```
$app->get('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($view) {
    $param = $request->getParams();

    $view->assign('name', $param["name"]);
    $response = $view->display('index.html');

    return $response;
});
```

If you *must* use a global, just use the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword:

```
$app->get('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) {    
    global $view;
    $param = $request->getParams();

    $view->assign('name', $param["name"]);
    $response = $view->display('index.html');

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you would use a closure, like this:

```
$app->get('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) 
    use ($view) { 
  // ... code ... $view is defined here
}
```

You can also call use by reference (i.e. `use (&$view)`) to be able to modify the variable in the closure scope.

See documentation in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.